# Can I use double quotes in Chef attribute declaration?

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

I have inherited a cookbook that sets some attributes in the ./attributes/default.rb file as per normal.

However, we have a problem with one of the lines is, which is:

```
default["obscured"]["mysql"] = "#{node['jboss']['jboss_home']}/modules/com/mysql/jdbc/main"
```

When run, it write this into the node as:

```
{}/com/mysql/jdbc/main
```

I can confirm that the node['jboss']['jboss_home'] attribute exists and has correct values.

So, I cannot see any problem with the above, except that every other declaration of this type in our cookbooks has single quotes on the attribute to be set (i.e. left side), not double quotes. I haven't heard this of as being an issue before, but I am pretty new to chef.

Is there any rule that says they must be single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is no rule.

Using double-quotes in something like this is completely fine:

```
default["obscured"]["mysql"] = blah blah
```

The reason I know that is that I just found one being set, with double quotes, that actually works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is fine, how are you confirming the value of `node['jboss']['jboss_home']` and how are you using it in the template?

In Ruby single and double quoted literals both become `String`s but single quotes are relatively literal while double quotes allow backslash escapes and `#{}` interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely hitting the derived attributes problem:

https://coderanger.net/derived-attributes/

The attribute code in your cookbook is getting parsed before the `jboss_home` attribute is being set. One way or another the solution is to move the interpolation into recipe code.

You could just use a plain old ruby variable instead of the attribute you are trying to construct -- particularly if nothing else in your system ever sets that attribute.

You also should be able to delete the declaration from your attributes file and use this in recipe code as well:

```
node.default_unless["obscured"]["mysql"] =
    "#{node['jboss']['jboss_home']}/modules/com/mysql/jdbc/main"
```

Although you need to place that statement early in your run_list, before you ever use `node["obscured"]["mysql"]` as an argument to any resource.